# How to convert from one date format to other format?

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl, date

I have one problem with my date format. I want to change from one format to the other and vice versa. My date formats are

Format 1

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Format 2

```
MM/DD/YYYY
```

I want to change format 1 to format 2 and  format 2 to format 1 .

Comment: o be more clear, I have the file 
file1 name: date
2000-01-01
2000-01-02
2000-01-03
2000-01-04

..

Required output is

01/01.2000
01/02/2000
01/03/2000
01/02/2000

and vice versal

Comment: Forward-slashes are one of the only two characters that cannot be in a *nix filename...

Answer (score 22):

Use GNU 'date' for this.  It will also convert between other formats for you (see `date --help` for the list of formats).

```
$ date -d 2013-07-05 +%m/%d/%Y
07/05/2013
$ date -d 07/05/2013 +%F
2013-07-05
```

Comment: to be more clear, I have the file 
file1 name: date
2000-01-01
2000-01-02
2000-01-03
2000-01-04

..

Required output is

01/01.2000
01/02/2000
01/03/2000
01/02/2000

and vice versal

Comment: @Abraham how does this not meet that requirement?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have dates in text form that need to be converted

```
echo '2013-12-13' | awk -v FS=- -v OFS=/ '{print $2,$3,$1}'
```

And vice-versa

```
echo '12/13/2013' | awk -v FS=/ -v OFS=- '{print $3,$1,$2}'
```

Comment: to be more clear, I have the file 
file1 name: date
2000-01-01
2000-01-02
2000-01-03
2000-01-04

..

Required output is

01/01.2000
01/02/2000
01/03/2000
01/02/2000

and vice versal

Comment: Thank you 1_CR, It is working now after I modified a little bit!!                                  #!/bin/bash

echo '$1-$2-$3' | awk -v FS=- -v OFS=/ '{print $2,$3,$1}' data.file

Comment: @Abraham, you should try your luck with drewbenn's `date` approach, that is certainly more elegant

Answer (score 4):

```
$ echo YYYY-MM-DD | { IFS=- read y m d && echo "$m/$d/$y"; }
MM/DD/YYYY
```

If you have a file with a lot of those dates, one per line:

```
awk -F- -vOFS=/ '{print $2,$3,$1}' < that-file
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering the clarified question in the comments about how to change the date format in a filename, use a variant of drewbenn's `gnu date` approach. This command finds all files in the local folder, and pipes only the file name to `xargs`, substituting the `date` modified filename as the second argument to `mv` which performs the rename.

The additional, slightly circuitous use of `bash` variable substitution is necessary as `bash` evaluates the `date` command.

```
find ./ -printf '%f\n' | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'mv $1  $(date -j -f %Y-%m-%d $1 +%m/%d%Y)' -- {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed as follows:

```
$ echo '2013-12-13' | sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]{2,4})-([[:digit:]]{1,2})-([[:digit:]]{1,2})/\2\/\3\/\1/g'
12/13/2013
$ echo '12/13/2013' | sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]{1,2})\/([[:digit:]]{1,2})\/([[:digit:]]{2,4})/\3-\1-\2/g'
2013-12-13
```