# change date/time format from yyyymmddHHMMss to dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss

Tags: shell-script, command-line, scripting, date, aix

How do I change date/time format from `yyyymmddHHMMss` to `dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss`

which is displayed as an output (eg. JOBNAME1 STARTED AT 20180904152402)

from a command...

```
grep JOBNAME1 | sed -e s/|/ /g | awk {print $3,$7,$8,$9} |sort -r -k 4
```

Comment: Answers to this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89568/how-to-convert-from-one-date-format-to-other-format should get you on the right track.

Comment: ick, your desired date format is ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

```
d='\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)'
sed "s|$d$d$d$d$d$d$d|\4/\3/\1\2 \5:\6:\7|g"
```

So for your code:

```
d='\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)'
awk -F'|' '/JOBNAME1/ {print $3,$7,$8,$9}' | sort -rk 4 |
  sed "s|$d$d$d$d$d$d$d|\4/\3/\1\2 \5:\6:\7|g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Painfully ugly awk method:

```
echo JOBNAME1 STARTED AT 20180904152402 | awk '{$4=substr($4,7,2)"/"substr($4,5,2)"/"substr($4,1,4)" "substr($4,9,2)":"substr($4,11,2)":"substr($4,13,2); print}'
```

Comment: Yay....it worked...thanx alot for your help....